# Change default back button on navigation view

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

Hi i am trying to change the title and icon of the default back button after pushing in a panel. I have tried the below code in the controller and i have tried similar code in the config of the view but with no success. Any direction on implementing this would be helpful

```
       this.getPlacesNavView().push({ xtype: 'details',title: name,
        backButton:{ iconCls:'reply', iconMask: true,  useTitleForBackButtonText: false,
        defaultBackButtonText: 'Back To Places'}});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question.

`backButton` is component of `navigationBar` config. So you can define it inside `navigationBar` config of *navigation view*  like this --

```
navigationBar : {
    backButton : {
        align : 'left',
        hidden : true,
        ui : 'back',
        iconMask: true,
        iconCls:'reply'

    }
}
```

From controller you need get instance of `navigationBar` and then `backButton`. And then set required properties. First push the desired view and then change back button-

```
this.getPlacesNavView().push({
        xtype: 'details',
        title: name
    });
var backButton = this.getPlacesNavView().getNavigationBar().getBackButton();
        backButton.setText("Back To Places");
        backButton.setIconMask(true);
        backButton.setIconCls("reply");
```

[Here is demonstration](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#xR5zh)

Answer (score -2):

```
var objView={
            xtype: 'navigationview',
            id: 'idContenido',
            **useTitleForBackButtonText: false,
            defaultBackButtonText: 'SIGUIENTE',**     
            navigationBar: {
                ui: 'sencha',
                *backButton: {
                            iconCls: 'compose',
                            iconMask: true,
                            ui: 'decline'
                             }*
            }
}
```